# piecewise linear approximation of $x^2$

Tags: approximation

Take the function $f(x) = x^2$. I read that it can be written as $$f(x) \approx k_1\cdotΔx_1 + k_2\cdotΔx_2 + \dots +k_n\cdot \Delta x_n,$$ where $k_n$ is the slope of the $n$-th piecewise linear block, and $\Delta x_n$ is the $n$-th linear block.

How is this derived? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 2):

The graph here explains exactly your problem [here >>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFinite_element_method_1D_illustration1.svg)

As you see it is piece wise linear and the slopes you have already captured intuitively.
So the smaller the $\Delta$ linear pieces (and the more of them in terms of $n$) the better the approximtaion.

---

From the definition of slope

$$k_i=\frac{\Delta y_i}{\Delta x_i}$$

derive $n$ pieces of lines:

$$\Delta y_i=k_i\cdot \Delta x_i$$

and sum over $n$:

$$f(x)=y\approx\sum^n_{i=1}\Delta y_i=\Delta y_1 + \Delta y_2+\dots+\Delta y_n= k_1\cdotΔx_1 + k_2\cdotΔx_2 + \dots +k_n\cdot \Delta x_n$$

so:
$$f(x) \approx k_1\cdotΔx_1 + k_2\cdotΔx_2 + \dots +k_n\cdot \Delta x_n$$

Comment: I cannot understand why the k1*Δx1 is the first line, and the k2*Δx2 is the second line etc.

I know that a line is : y=k*x + b, where k is the slope. But I cannot figure out the k*Δx formula!

Comment: made an add above.